# What are good ways to reduce the number of dependencies?

Tags: dependency-injection

I am using dependency injection for quite some time and I really like the technique, but I often have a problem of too many dependencies that should be injected 4 - 5 which seems to much.

But I cannot find a way to make it simpler. For instance I have a class with some business logic that sends messages, it accepts two other business logic dependencies to do what is needed (one to translate data to messages sent, and one to translate messages that are received).

But apart from this it needs some "technical" dependencies like `ILogger`, `ITimerFactory` (because it needs to create timers inside), `IKeyGenerator` (to generate unique keys).

So the whole list grows pretty big. Are there any good common ways to reduce the number of dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle those is to refactor towards Aggregates (or Facades). Mark Seemann wrote a good article on it, [check it out](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) (actually I highly recommend [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) as well, just saying).
So say you have the following (as taken from the article):

```
public OrderProcessor(IOrderValidator validator,
                      IOrderShipper shipper,
                      IAccountsReceivable receivable,
                      IRateExchange exchange,
                      IUserContext userContext)
```

You can refactor it to:

```
public OrderProcessor(IOrderValidator validator,
                      IOrderShipper shipper,
                      IOrderCollector collector)
```

Where `OrderCollector` is a facade (it wraps the previous 3 dependencies):

```
public OrderCollector(IAccountsReceivable receivable,
                      IRateExchange exchange,
                      IUserContext userContext)
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

In terms of the cross-cutting concerns (logging and caching for example) and a strategy to handle them, here is a suggestion (that's what I usually do), say you have the following:

```
public interface IOrderService
{
    void DoAwesome();
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public void DoAwesome()
    {
        // do your thing here ... no logging no nothing
    }
}
```

Here I'd use the decorator pattern to create an OrderService that has logging enabled:

```
public class OrderServiceWithLogging : IOrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public OrderServiceWithLogging(IOrderService orderService, ILogger logger)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoAwesome()
    {
        _orderService.DoAwesome();
        _logger.Log("Awesome is done!");
    }
}
```

It might look like a bit of overhead but IMHO, it's clean and testable.

Another way would be to go into Aspect Oriented Programming and look into concepts such as interception, where basically you intercept certain method calls and perform tasks as a result. Many DI frameworks (I wanna say all?) support interception, so that might be something that you prefer.

Comment: In his article he really factored out one facade that utilizes stuff that is called one by one so it's possible to gather in one facade. But my dependencies do not share the same kind of logic... For instance how do you join logger and timer factory?

Comment: I wouldn't, logger is a cross-cutting concern (IMHO), I'd employ a different strategy.

Comment: So any suggestions for this different strategy?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I've done a little edit, since it's going to be long for the comment section.